# How to make home path display from sub-route using React Router Dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

- [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)
- [www.mysite.com/](http://www.mysite.com/)
- [www.mysite.com/1](http://www.mysite.com/1)

I want my site to display the same page for each of the above routes. Currently it displays nothing for [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) and [www.mysite.com/](http://www.mysite.com/)

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Products />}>
          <Route path="/:id" element={<ProductDisplay />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Products component

```
function Products() {
  return (
    <div className="products">
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}


export default Products;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `ProductDisplay` component to render on `"/"` as well as `"/:id"` then render an additional index route that will match with the parent route path.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Products />}>
          <Route index element={<ProductDisplay />} /> // <-- renders on "/"
          <Route path="/:id" element={<ProductDisplay />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

See [Index Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#index-routes) for more details.

Comment: I'm surprised that's the best way, I would have thought the DRY principle would mean you shouldn't do this? Thanks for taking the time to answer, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Ry2254 Welcome, glad to help. Yeah, RRDv6 was a bit of a departure from v5. You may also find this [answer](/a/70009104/8690857) regarding optional parameters interesting, which is close to the use case you are describing. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Whats the best practice to handle my useParams getting a NaN on the index path?

Comment: @Ry2254 Checking for a truthy `id` value. `const { id } = useParams();` and `if (id) { .....}`. You could also use the destructuring assignment to assign a fallback value, i.e. `const { id = "the fallback value" } = useParams();`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did this: const { id = 1 } = useParams();

Comment: @Ry2254 lol, yeah, exactly that.  Though I'd suggest using a string value to maintain any invariants since the route path params will ***always*** be a string type.